# Arduino and Windows 7

Tags: arduino, windows

I have problems with Arduino Mega drivers on Windows 7.

I've downloaded  newest driver from http://www.ftdichip.com/FTDrivers.htm, but i cant install driver.

I've installed  USB Serial Converted, but USB Serial Port dosen't work (i tried to reinstal driver, but it don't bring any effect).

I've used this below instruction:

- In Windows 7 the FTDI driver is plug and play (windows should identify that it has been plugged in and
  can automatically download/install the correct driver)
- If this doesn't work download the FTDI drivers from: http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm
- Make sure you're using the latest JRE in 32-bit (even if you run 64-bit)

.... and it doesn't bring any effect too. Could you help me?

Comment: Have you tested your Arduino on a different, working, system? I'd do that, to rule out problems with the Arduino.

Comment: can you please clarify, when you plug in the arduino, does the power light on the arduino come on, and windows indicate that a device has been plugged into the computer (recognized or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any problems using a Duemilanove with Win7 x64.

Try the Arduino forum.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't need any drivers at all to use the arduino.  FTDI chips appear as vanilla serial devices on the USB chain, and should appear as a regular COM port after being connected.  Sometimes the numbered port is quite high, and might not be obvious which one it is.  Go to the hardware/device manager and find the FTDI device in the list of USB devices, then check its properties to determine which COM port it landed on.

You might also need to close and reopen the arduino IDE to see the arduino appear in the list of serial ports.

**EDIT** Alternately:

Arduinos have a jumper near the power plug which selects where the arduino receives power, in one position, it receives power over the USB connection, and in the other position it receives power from an external 9volt source.  make sure the jumper is set to receive power from USB.

Answer (score 0):

I've used FTDI USB-serial chips on Win 7 x64 before, but not Arduino itself. I didn't need to install any drivers. So don't worry if the driver doesn't install.

Does the serial port show up in the list of available ports after you connect the USB cable?

Answer (score 0):

Have just completed a fresh Windows 7 Professional x64 installation last month, Windows took care of everything when I plugged in the FTDI cable for the first time. Follow TokenMacGuy's suggestions as well.