# Problem building Arduino Uno firmware

Tags: arduino, avr, firmware

I am trying to build the Arduino firmware on Win7 using WinAVR and FLIP. I have successfully built the firmware and have a "arduino-usbserial.hex" file to upload, but when I flash the Uno and plug it back in to my computer Windows no longer recognizes the device and won't use the Arduino drivers for it. If I reflash to the "arduino-usbserial-uno.hex" file that comes in the folder everything works fine. Am I missing a part of the build process? My steps are

- set arduino to DFU mode (connect jumper and release)
- make clean
- make all
- manually download with Flip via USB (run, start application, then unplug and plug in)

The makefile has the `ARDUINO_MODEL_PID` set to 0x0001 and `MCU = atmega8u2`

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. The question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller - The question is about compiling firmware for an embedded platform.  You're right, our site isn't for *all* programming, but programming is an important part of electronics design.  This is, IMO, on-topic.  Feel free to ask on meta if you're confused.

Comment: @LeonHeller This has come up before. We have many questions along the same lines as this that aren't closed. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9444/arduino-programming-on-uno-fails-using-usb-download-on-windows-2000 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/arduino-and-windows-7 and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8746/arduino-control-panel-for-windows and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10708/problem-installing-icd3-windows-driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, problem found. The Vendor ID and the Product ID of the firmware was changed in subsequent *non-factory* firmware releases which prevented the Arduino drivers from recognizing it. The solution is to use either the drivers in the LUFA project folders, or change these lines in `Descriptors.c`

```
.VendorID               = 0x03EB, // Atmel
.ProductID              = 0x204B, // LUFA USB to Serial Demo Application
```

to this

```
.VendorID               = 0x2341, // Arduino
.ProductID              = 0x0001,
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.